# Review on rejected edit

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I had a suggested edit rejected on the accepted answer to the following question earlier today:
[C# WebBrowser Control System.AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178898/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-system-accessviolationexception/270312#270312)

The current link within the answer directs to the following page, which is an invalid page on the site showing the message "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist.":
http://jtstroup.net/post/Attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-This-is-often-an-indication-that-other-memory-is-corrupt.aspx

I followed the history on the blog until I found the same article, in order to update the answer to the new url of the blog post, showing below:
http://cyberencoding.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected.html

However this edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5670008) for the reason "This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost."

If it is just updating the link to the same blog post, surely this can't be changing the original meaning or intent, as the link is currently broken (arguably damaging it more).

Is there a method on Stack Overflow to appeal or have the edit reviewed, as I found the blog post useful in solving my issue.

Comment: Out of interest what did you type in as the edit summary? As an aside, this is exactly why link-only answers are rubbish.

Comment: "Updated URL, as current is not valid."

Comment: There's no appeal. You can suggest the edit again, or post a comment.

Comment: "Updated URL, as current is not valif." is not the most informative edit summary

Comment: Why bother? Post the link as a comment, flag the answer NAA.

Comment: @gnat - Why do you say that?  Such an edit summary specifies exactly what was done.

Comment: @bjb568 - If the system isn't working properly in the small ways, it won't be there when it's needed in the big ways.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Well, I'd say the "system" worked fine here, the edit was too minor.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum [meta-tag:edit-summary] is large enough to put a bit more details there. What exactly is "not valid", is it plain 404, or there is irrelevant content there, or message that content has moved to some other site etc. How was "updated URL" discovered, via Google search, or someone pointed to it in comments etc

Comment: @gnat - I think that by expecting that level of detail in a simple edit summary, it drives away those with limited time who nonetheless specify their edits sufficiently in the edit summary to make the general (valid) edit's purpose clear.  Let me ask you: have you undertaken the effort to write that level of detail for **every** edit you've ever made?  If not, do you think those edits for which you did not specify that much detail should either have been rejected or not made to begin with?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum when I consider it important for my suggestion to pass through review I invest as much effort as possible into edit summary ([learned about this rather hard way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146346/165773))

Comment: @gnat - When I review edit suggestions I invest strong effort in giving the benefit of the doubt when deciding whether to accept or reject edits.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum not all reviewers are like you. Again, when I consider my suggestion important, I try to make summary such that it would look good for _the worst kind_ reviewers, simply because there's no way tell who will review it

Comment: @gnat - And, not all those who make edits are like you.  Some do not realize that there will be overzealous reviewers who will insist on unnecessarily detailed edit summaries, and sadly this means that in some cases valid edits are rejected.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum that's the price we pay for allowing 30,000 users (2Kers) review edit suggestions. Raising the bar higher would make it slower, one has to compromise anyway

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally such edits are fine, I occasionally make such edits by finding the new URL or by finding a copy on the [archive.org](http://archive.org/web/) site. Try to be slightly more descriptive in your edit summary, something like this should do:

> Link is broken, replaced with the new location.

or

> Link is broken, replaced with an archived version.

In this case it's a link-only answer, so it should have been a comment instead. While the reject reason is completely incorrect, I would have rejected the edit myself.

[As @bjb568 said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270349/review-on-rejected-edit#comment88157_270349), post the link as a comment and flag the answer as *not an answer*.

Comment: I did try to add the link as a comment to begin with, but I did not have the necessary permissions.

Comment: @ahillier88 There is a reason for that - if new users see an opportunity to comment, wait until you are more experienced and have 50 rep, then see if it is a good comment or not, and if it is, post it.

Comment: I already have more than 50 reputation, maybe it was because the question was closed?

Comment: This answers one aspect of the original question.  Do you know the answer to the other?  Does StackExchange have a mechanism to appeal edit reviews?

Comment: @ColinvH No, there's no built-in mechanism to appeal them. Sometimes they are discussed in comments on the question/answer or here on Meta, but that's only for exceptional cases.